# no name in the given module error in python (flask)

Tags: python, flask

New to web dev and while implementing routes an error occures,

firstly the code written is in website folder and inside that template subfolder which has all the the files like **init**.py and auth.py ...etc , now outside this template subfolder there is main function.

like this :
[image: here]

CODE IN **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='madkrish'

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views,url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth,url_prefix='/')

    return app
```

CODE IN auth.py

```
from flask import Blueprint



auth = Blueprint('auth',__name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return "<p>Login</p>"


@auth.route('/logout')
def logout():
    return "<p>Logout</p>"    


@auth.route('/sign-up')
def sign-up():
    return "<p>Sign Up</p>"
```

CODE IN main.py

```
from templates import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When i run the main.py the following error comes :
[image: this]

No name 'auth' in module 'templates.auth'

Can someone please correct me where i am wrong so that i can proceed to the next part of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change your project layout.

Your `main.py` should be in the same directory as the `website` folder, so 1 folder up.

Then, your `__init__.py`, `auth.py`, `views.py` and `models.py` files should be in the `website` folder, so 1 directory up for those as well.

In the end, your project should be structured like this:

```
project_folder/
├── main.py
└── website
    ├── static
    ├── templates
    ├── auth.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    └── views.py
```

Of course this also means you will have to change your `import` statement in `main.py`:

```
from website import create_app
```

You can import from `website` because the code exists in the `__init__.py` file.

Let me know if this works for you.

#### Edit: Quick side note

The `templates` folder is where you will put your html files, and the `static` folder is where you will put your css, javascript and other files that don't change (unlike your templates which do). Therefore your core `.py` files for running the website should not go in either of those folders, but in the website folder itself.

My initial project structure with flask usually looks something like this:

```
project_folder/
├── main.py
└── website
    ├── auth.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── style.css
    │   └── index.js
    ├── templates
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── home.html
    │   ├── login.html
    │   ├── sign_up.html
    └── views.py
```